# How can I reorder bones and keep the same hierarchy?

Tags: interface, outliner

[image]

[image]

I am needing to match one of my armatures to another one, but the placement of bones are not in the correct order (even though they are both parented to the same item, it does not matter in my case). I have tried re-parenting objects to a temporary bone, then re-parenting to the head bone, but they seem to remember where they were before.

I've done a bit of searching and it seems this may be a limitation of the outliner, but I thought I'd try asking here just in case something has changed.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the error I was getting in unreal on importing my models wasn't due to incorrect bone index. I was getting my bones renamed on import in unreal because I had meshes that had the same name as the bones. Whoops!